# How to encode correclty an url with the char "&" for an email?

Tags: urls, encoding, html-email

In a plugin I need to send an email to confirm a member registration.
Inside this email HTML Content, there is a link with two parameters like this :

```
site_url() . "/user-profile/?activate=true&token=" . $token
```

My problem is the char "&" which prevent to send the email.

I tested the function `esc_url()` without success.

What is the WP solution ?

Comment: You could try `&amp;` - if that doesn't work you will probably need to provide more of your code as it's not clear why an ampersand would cause issues with the rest of your code.

Comment: "My problem is the char "&" which prevent to send the email" > What do you mean by that, post any error messages in your question, pls.